# running cron in google app engine gives 404 error

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, cron

My cronjob does not run when I click Run Now in http://localhost:8000/cron

[image: 404 error screenshot]

My app contains the following files
hello.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"\
        self.response.write("Congratulations, it's a web app!")

    routes = [('/', MainPage)]
    my_app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes, debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: hello
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: hello.my_app

- url: /tasks/summary
  script: hello.application
```

cron_script.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class CronTask(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        f = open("test.txt","w") #opens file with name of "test.txt"
        f.write("I am a test file.")
        f.write("Maybe someday, he will promote me to a real file.")
        f.write("Man, I long to be a real file")
        f.write("and hang out with all my new real file friends.")
        f.close()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/tasks/summary', CronTask)],
                                 debug=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: daily summary job
  url: /tasks/summary
  target: beta
  schedule: every 1 minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `cron.yaml` file will make requests to `/tasks/summary`.

Your `app.yaml` directs them to your `hello.application`.

But your matching `hello.py` file doesn't have a matching route for `/tasks/summary`.

You could expand your existing route pattern to match that path:

```
routes = [('/.*', MainPage)]
```

But more likely you'll add specific route for it (and you'll need to add the matching handler code for it as well):

```
routes = [('/tasks/summary', CronHandler)]
```